# Appengine migration to HRD datastore stuck on copy phase

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I just tried starting a migration from a master/slave datastore to an HRD datastore app. The migration tool got stuck in the first "copy" phase for over 24 hours. I don't have a lot of data so this was unexpected so just then I tried to revert the migration. Now it's stuck in the "copy reverting step".

There doesn't seem to be any diagnostics in what has gone wrong or how to rectify it. What are the next steps I should try?

Update: As an update I did also log a ticket with Google and after over 48hrs I did get a response that they're looking for a fix. I'll post an update if there is any useful root cause identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit confusing as the Google help documents point to StackOverlow for help and don't mention the issue tracker (at least it wasn't obvious to me).

Turns out the only way to get this fixed is to log a ticket at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list.

It was an internal problem with the migration script and there wasn't anything particularly wrong with my data or that I could of done to fix it.

It took 5 days for someone to respond to my ticket and rectify the issue so be patient.